# XmlSerializer -> case insensitive

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

I am wondering if there is a way to use the XmlSerializer to deserialize objects with different casing.

Lets say my object is

```
Class A
{
  public String Str{get;set;}
}
```

I have the following XML files, id like to deserialize:

```
<root><StR>Hello</StR></root>

<root><STR>Hello</STR></root>

<root><str>Hello</str></root>
```

Any Suggestions/Ideas? Also approachs manipulating the DOM, etc are welcome :)

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
xml_str=xml_str.Replace("StR>","Str>");
```

or simply preform XSLT transformation before you desirlize

Comment: Also if this does not solve anything, i use an xslt, that i embed into the assembly.

Answer (score 1):

XML is case sensitive, so in this case I'd say it would fail. So you should cleanse the data using regex as the DOM will have issues with the XML.

Answer (score 0):

Since Xml is case sensitive you cannot achieve this behavior automatically. One way to solve the problem is to implement the `IXmlSerializable` interface. This way you can control the xml deserialization in the `ReadXml(XmlReader reader)` method.